# Internet Explorer 11 not recognising CSS3 specific properties

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have switched from IE8 to IE11, but still I am not able to use CSS3 properties. IE11 not recognising the CSS3 specific porperties like border-radius and box-shadow.

In the developer tools they are without a check box and are red underlined.

A possible reason which I have found is that the doctype html is always commented out and I assume that because of that IE is not recognising the properties.

Comment: is the doctype commented out in the source code or just in the code-view?

Comment: can you show the css

Comment: IE may be running on an older view engine. In developer tools "Emulation" tab what does it show the document mode as?

Comment: I have noticed that IE11 is starting always in Document type 8 and with Browser Profile as 'Enterprise'. When I Change it to edge everything works fine. The site is running on Intranet. How can I force IE11 to start i edge mode. I have set X-UA-Compatible to IE=edge in my master template .xhtml file but it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this website: http://caniuse.com/

It will show a guide as to what CSS and general web design rules work with which browsers with and without plugin support.

Border radius: http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

Boxshadow : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow

The graphs output on these links show that both these CSS rules work in IE above IE8.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Emil I have added clarity to my answer. I can't replicate the actual link content but I hope this helps?